# How to make multiple filters over an array, in the context of an async function?

Tags: javascript, filter

I am making this little program that works with an employee API. What I want to do is to filter the results of the employee list, when i click over the checkboxes. For the moment only the "married" filter is working.  I am having trouble with one important thing:

I don't know how to combine multiple filters. What if i want to get all the employees that are married and that have allergies? How do I consider all the possibilites?

```
    <body>
<div class="filter-container">

  <label for="married">married</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="married" value="" id = "married">
  <label for="married">allergies</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="allergies" value="" id = "allergies">
  <label for="married">has-family</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="family" value="" id = "family">

</div>
<ul class = 'employees'>

</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">

  async function getEmployees() {

    const response = await fetch ("test.json");
    const data = await response.json();
    printEmployees(data.employees)
  };

  function printEmployees(employees){
    const employeesList = document.querySelector(".employees");
    while(employeesList.firstChild) {
      employeesList.removeChild(employeesList.firstChild)
    };
    const employeesContainer = document.createElement('div');
    for (const employee of employees) {
      const li = document.createElement("li");

      li.innerHTML = `<p> name : ${employee.name} </p>
                      <p> job : ${employee.job} </p>
                      <p> family : ${employee.family} </p>
                      <p> allergies : ${employee.allergies} </p>
                      <p> married : ${employee.married} </p>`
     employeesContainer.appendChild(li);
   }
    employeesList.appendChild(employeesContainer);
   }

  const married = document.getElementById("married");
  married.addEventListener("click" , function () {marriedFilter()})

async function marriedFilter(){

    const response = await fetch ("test.json");
    const data = await response.json();
    const employees = data.employees;
    const marriedEmployees = employees.filter(employee => employee.married == "yes");

    if (married.checked == true) {
        printEmployees(marriedEmployees)}
    else {
        printEmployees(employees)}

    }
   getEmployees();


</script>

  </body>
```

THE JSON

```
{ "employees" :
        [ {
        "name" : "John",
        "job" : "Web developer",
        "married" : "yes",
        "allergies" : "yes",
        "family" : "no"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Alejandra",
        "job" : "Cooker",
        "married" : "no",
        "allergies" : "no",
        "family" : "no"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Pedro",
        "job" : "footballer",
        "married" : "no",
        "allergies" : "yes",
        "family" : "no"
    },
    {
        "name" : "John",
        "job" : "cooker",
        "married" : "no",
        "allergies" : "no",
        "family" : "no"

    },
    {
        "name" : "Billie",
        "job" : "Cooker",
        "married" : "no",
        "allergies" : "yes",
        "family" : "yes"

    },
    {
        "name" : "Slash",
        "job" : "Web developer",
        "married" : "yes",
        "allergies" : "no",
        "family" : "yes"

    }
        ]}
```

Comment: Side note; consder *not* refetching the data every time a filter changes.  Store the results and reuse them.

Comment: you can cascade filters like this. `employees.filter(e => e.married == "yes").filter(e => e. allergies == "yes");`

Comment: taplar, is it better to store the whole JSON result in a variable, so i just fetch it once?

Comment: D. Seah, so I should create a function for every filter I want to make, and put those cascades filters inside?